# Java XML: How to force wildcard (xs:any) strict matching?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have a bunch of external XSDs which I can't change.
They use wildcard content models `(xs:any`) with `processContents="skip"`.

**Question:**

Is there a programmatic way in java/JAXP to force wildcard (`xs:any`) `processContents="strict"` matching instead (without changing the XSDs)?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use Java to modify the schema before using it for validation. You don't have to change the original schema, just the one that you're validating against.

If you're using XSD 1.1 you could create the locally-modified schema using `xs:override`.

Comment: This means that whenever the original schema file changes, I have to adapt my "modified" version which is what works (and what I am currently doing) but does not really answer my question.

Comment: `xs:override` is designed to do exactly what you want: define what's different without redefining everything that's the same. But you could achieve exactly the same with a custom XSLT transformation. The answer to your question as stated is obviously "no" (you can't change a schema without changing the schema), but I didn't think that was helpful.